# Printing diamonds from *'s

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am trying to System.out.print() a diamond out of *'s. So far I have spent a good 5 hours on trying to figure out how to reverse print the bottom triangle of the diamond. 
I can worry about the spacing to complete the diamond later. (I have it worked for the most part).

If someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong and how the right way works I would greatly appreciate it.

```
private static void diamond()
    {
        int numLines = 0;
        System.out.println("How many lines would you like in the Diamond?");
        numLines = scan.nextInt();

        if (numLines / 2 == 0)  //if number is even, make odd.
        {
            numLines++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= numLines ; i++)   // Controls #Lines
        {
            if(i <= numLines / 2)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < i * 2 - 1; j++) // Controls #Stars small upright triangle
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int k = numLines; k > i / 2; k--)   // Controls # of spaces
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                /*for(int j = numLines/2 - i, l = i; l > j; j++) // Controls #Stars small upright triangle
                {
                    String stars = "*";
                    System.out.print(stars);
                }*/
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: DurzoBlunt for even number use % instead of / (((4/2 = 2) != 0), ((4%2) = 0))
please post your expected result for an example :)

Comment: Post your code so we can see.

Comment: Do **not** post screenshots of code. Paste the code into your question so we can read it, copy and paste it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is my 1st post on here. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What happens to your attempt is that you loop through the half (of the lines) of your diamond [the number of lines in second/first half] times.

You'd want to do a if-statement each loop, not an if *and* a for in each loop

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want this

Just adjust it for user input values

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Reverse diamond: \n");
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\n\nDiamond from starts: \n");
        for (int i = 7; i > 0; i -= 2) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
}
```

**output:**

[image]